# To show current street location on Google Map over Website by using Mobile

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have to let user know their current location (street location) with Google Map, on my Website which will be accessing via Mobile Phones / Mobile Devices. How can it be done?

Note: Direct via Website. No native App will be using.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this will only work on a mobile phone that supports [W3C Geo API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). You can find that list on [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html).

Given a mobile phone that supports this, follow the example in the [Google Maps API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Geolocation) where you use the GeoLocation API to get your longitude/latutide, and then use the standard Google Maps API to center a map on screen at this location.

Comment: When i follow the Google Maps API, my device location is showing the location of my ISP on the map.  :( And to be honest, i don't get exactly what you mean above.

Comment: If you are seeing the location of your ISP, then everything works - there is no guarantee that you will get street location. In this case, your phone can only provide the location of your ISP (based on either IP lookup or WiFi access point). It is not using GPS to get your street location because a) You're indoors and it can't get a GPS fix, b) your phone doesn't have a GPS chip, c) Your phone doesn't provide very accurate location to javascript for privacy reasons.  These things vary, and will vary for your users so your app needs to take this into account.